# React. Props error when try to use forEach function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to send the props from parent component `Row` by condition via `forEach` iterator I even get the `undefined` in the child component.

I cannot figure out what is the problem is...

```
 // Parent component
 // ... class Row extends...
     // ... some code
      render() {
        const canSelector = {
           selectedItems: []
        }
        return (
            <Row showImage={canSelector.selectedItems.forEach(item => { 
                   item.ID === i ? 'item' : 'error'}) }
            />
          }            
        )


// Child component for test
// ... class XXX extends...
         // ... some code
         const { showImage } = this.props
         console.log(showImage); // gets "undefined", intead of "error" string
```

Comment: Am i the only one to not see `forEach` anywhere in the implementation?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh yep! thank you, I just also makes some tests. Change in post this moment

Comment: `forEach` by definition returns `undefined`

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza and?... How you can help

Comment: Well, It depends on your needs, what do you want to pass to the `Row` component? a mapping of `canSelector.selectedItems` ? a single value?  or what ?

Comment: try `map` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza it must be an array as show in the post `canSelector .selectedItems`

Comment: @riwu map also does not work

Comment: That's because you array is empty

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza You can try to fill it and make test. It is not a problem is.

Comment: Use `map` and remove the `{}` or add `return` in the map function.

Comment: What's `i` inside `render`

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything, that is the reason that you are getting `undefined` as the value of `showImage` in your `<Row />` component.

I assume that you are trying to check if the `item.ID` has the same value as `i`, and return `'item'` or `'error'` accordingly?

You might want to check [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead.

You can do something like this:

```
<Row showImage={canSelector.selectedItems.findIndex(item => item.ID === i) > -1 ? 'item' : 'error'} />
```

`findIndex()` will return the index of the first item in the array that satisfy the condition provided, else it will return `-1`.